# AG-Grid: Drag and drop column to pinned area not working from sidebar

Tags: ag-grid

I have an ag-grid with three columns pinned to the left side:

```
var columnDefs = [
  {headerName: "Column 1", field: "col1", pinned: 'left'},
  {headerName: "Column 2", field: "col2", pinned: 'left'},
  {headerName: "Column 3", field: "col3", pinned: 'left'}, 
etc.
]
```

I am also using the Side Bar to display the Columns Tool Panel and allow reordering of the columns:

```
sideBar: {          
  toolPanels: [
    {
    id: 'columns',
    labelKey: 'columns',
    iconKey: 'menu',
    toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',

    toolPanelParams: {
            suppressRowGroups: true,
            suppressValues: true,
            suppressPivots: true,
            suppressPivotMode: true,
            suppressColumnFilter: true,
            suppressColumnSelectAll: false,
            suppressColumnExpandAll: true,
     },
     },
   ],
   position: 'right',
}
```

I can drag and drop columns **in the grid** into the pinned area, but I cannot drag them within the Side Bar into the pinned area. For example, if I drag a column above Column 1, it doesn't drop there, but drops right after Column 3, which is the last pinned column.

I tried removing the tool Panel Params but that didn't work. I can un-pin the columns and that works, but I want to keep them pinned.